# Name and use own colors or color palette for ggplot graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, color-palette

I have some colors that I would like to give a name to be able to use them in ggplot graphs without having to write the hex codes by hand each time I write the code for a graph.

For example I have the following hex colors `#EBD0FC`, `#F0FFF0`, `#BEBEBE` that I would like to name `"mypink"`, `"mymint"`, `"mygrey"`.

```
mycolors <- 
  data.frame(name = c("mypink", "mymint", "mygrey"),
         hex = c("#EBD0FC", "#F0FFF0", "#BEBEBE"))
```

And I would like to use the colors in a ggplot graph like that:

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("mypink", "mymint", "mygrey"))
```

instead of

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#EBD0FC", "#F0FFF0", "#BEBEBE"))
```

As a follow up question: is there a way to "save" my color palette somewhere (online? and maybe only for me to access?) so that I do not have to specify it at the beginning of each session?

Comment: One option is to save your colours as objects, for example `mypink <- "#EBD0FC"` and use `mypink` in the call to `scale_fill_manual` etc. Another option is to create your own colour palette possibly in an internal package.

Comment: I don't think you can do _that_, but ... I often find that naming colors is useful when the name is set to specific values. For instance, if your data (to be plotted) has an aesthetic defined as `aes(fill=grp)` and the unique `grp` values are `"AA"`, `"BB"`, and `"CC"`, one typically does `scale_fill_manual(values = c(AA="#EBD0FC", BB="#F0FFF0", CC="#BEBEBE"))`. (But if you could use `"mypink"`, then you could do `c(AA="mypink", ...)`, so perhaps orthogonal to your question ... sorry.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function to translate your names into the hex you defined. for example.

```
mycolors <- 
  data.frame(name = c("mypink", "mymint", "mygrey"),
             hex = c("#EBD0FC", "#F0FFF0", "#BEBEBE"))

myc <- function(x){
  mycolors$hex[which(x %in% mycolors$name)]
}

waldo::compare(scale_fill_manual(values = c("#EBD0FC", "#F0FFF0", "#BEBEBE")),
          scale_fill_manual(values = myc(c("mypink", "mymint", "mygrey"))))
# ✔ No differences
```

Comment: I suggest two additions to the `myc` function: (1) define `mycolors` within it, often scope-breach like this can be difficult to troubleshoot; and (2) add a mechanism so that colors _not_ found are retained as-is and not replaced with `NA`. For the second, one can use `dplyr::coalesce` or `data.table::fcoalesce` (if already using one of those packages), or do `out <- mycolors$hex[...]; out[is.na(out)] <- x[is.na(out)]; out`.

Comment: `which(x %in% y)`  is a roundabout, inefficient way of writing `match(x, y)`.